# Convert union type to list of those types as literals

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

If I have a Typescript type like

```
type Mode = 'auto'|'manual';
```

Can I recover the list of them? Like

```
const modes: Mode[] = /*all the Modes */
```

Comment: In short, no... TypeScript's type system is erased when transpiled and has no runtime effects.  You can do the opposite, however... start with an array like `const modes = ["auto", "manual"] as const;` and then derive the type from it `type Mode = (typeof modes)[number]`

Comment: You could also just use a string enum, which creates both types and values: `enum Mode { auto = "auto", manual = "manual" }` -- this isn't quite the same thing as what you're asking for (frustratingly string enums are not exactly the same thing as literal type unions with values) but arguably it's the intended solution to your problem